# Dependency injection in a Junit test for a factory implementation

Tags: spring, junit

I have some API code upon which I have to provide a solution. I am looking into using spring with this code.

There is a factory interface, lets call it ABCFactory. It returns an instance of a service

```
public interface ABCFactory {
   XYZService getXYZService(); 
}
```

XYZService it's self is an interface as well.

Now I have a TestClass which I cannot modify. It uses some thing like

```
ABCFactory abcFactory = (ABCFactory) Class.forName(
            "com.me.blah.ABCFactoryImpl").newInstance();
```

I have to come up with ABCFactoryImpl, thats all good. But I don't get if it is possible to use dependency injection for ABCFactoryImpl. The Junit test has no knowledge of Spring. Is it even possible to *wire* every thing up, without making the Junit test aware of spring context.

PS: my knowledge of spring DI is at known-incompetence (I know how much I need to know/read)

Comment: Your best bet is to make the jUnit test Spring aware, otherwise you may still have dependencies that are not wired up. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to do changes within the Test class. Is there any other way to make the test spring aware?

Comment: Not really. The ex. test is using reflection to create the class using the jvm to manage instances. Spring / DI does the same thing but gives you a container to manage instances such that objects are typically created as faux singletons (1 instance, managed by Spring).

Comment: If you absolutely cannot make the unit test spring aware, you could initialize Spring in the constructor or static constructor of the implementing class to wire the additional dependencies.  However this design is very poor and is counter to using DI.  What happens to the test if your Impl class changes? The test must change too.  But if DI is used, the test can be injected with the new implementing class without requiring changes to the test.  Only the Spring configuration file or autowiring name changes.

Comment: You don't actually have to use Spring in order to use DI. The important part of DI (more or less) is that `ABCFactoryImpl` is passed in as a constructor argument (or setter argument), which receives the argument at type `ABCFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether abcFactory is a instance field, static field or local variable.

If it is an instance field or static field, you can try your luck by implementing a special JUnitRunner to do DI, and annotate the test case with @RunWith. You can also reuse the same Runner in other test cases.

I have done this to inject static field or instance field.